# How to calculate time spent in each place

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table as below:

```
DT1 <- 
      read.table(text = "
                            id         time                 place_id
                            604        2017-08-10 18:44:14    15
                            604        2017-08-10 20:38:20    15
                            604        2017-08-10 20:54:26    24
                            604        2017-08-10 21:35:50    24                            
                            604        2017-08-11 12:05:42    30
                            604        2017-08-11 13:05:42    30

                          ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

From this I want to calculate the time spent in each place_id by each id.

```
id     time  place_id
604     6846   15
604     2484   24
604     3600   30
```

I tried like this to get each group for each zone

```
DT1[,follow_group_new := cumsum(difftime(time, shift(time, fill=-Inf), units="mins") > 5), by=list(id,place_id)]
```

This gives me each group .Not sure how to get the desired output from there.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to compute the difference between the maximum amd the minimum timestamps per group of id and place_id. And of course you have to convert your time column to POSIXct before this operation.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT1)
DT1[, time := as.POSIXct(time)]
DT1[, .(time = difftime(max(time), min(time), units = "secs")),
      by = .(id, place_id)]
#     id place_id      time
# 1: 604       15 6846 secs
# 2: 604       24 2484 secs
# 3: 604       30 3600 secs
```